# How microcontrollers and development boards are usually programmed/interfaced?

Tags: c++, c, microcontroller

I have some experience in small projects with microcontrollers such as Arduino boards and ESP32. However, when programming these boards, you can usually use abstractions such as the Arduino IDE, which makes them very easy to program.

Indeed, I cannot manage to understand how microcontrollers (others than Arduino) are usually programmed under the hood. As far as I understand, usually, the manufacturers of microprocessors offer development boards to test their products, right? However, how are these microcontrollers/development boards usually programmed? With this I mean that there must be some code that is used to interface with the microcontroller, right? How is this "interfacing" code usually structured and how it works? Is there a common file system structure of this additional "interfacing" code? Is there something like a "main.c" file in which it must be written all your code and that is automatically executed when uploaded to the microcontroller? Is there any type of convention when it comes to programming microcontrollers? As well, how can you "upload" the code to a general microcontroller? For example, Arduino IDE makes this very easy (upload button and USB connection), but I suppose that this is not the usual method of "uploading" code when working with other microcontrollers, right?

Comment: Read specifications (it may be called as "user manual") of your microcontrollers and it may contain information of how to write programs to them.

Comment: Many microcontrollers have a JTAG interface that is used to 1) Program the microcontroller; 2) Debug and single step the microcontroller and 3) Perform a hardware scan.  Some microcontrollers can be set up to have their COM port used for programming the memory on the controller.  You'll have to check out the data sheets on your microcontroller.

Comment: You start with the documentation for each (specific) chip.  There are things like jtag (uncommon today too many pins), and i2c or spi like interfaces or uart, etc.  Very often they are specific to a vendor or family within a vendor (SWD for cortex-ms for example).  Older parts require higher voltages, etc.  Then look at the schematic/pcb to see if they have made the board to use one of these interfaces or possibly even if they didnt design for that.

Comment: Then you have things like some products come with a bootloader (programmed by the chip vendor, or burned in a mask rom, or something programmable but programmed by the product vendor).  And then this bootloader can support uart, i2c, spi, or custom interfaces.  Sometimes you need to hold a strap pin on reset (push a button for example, move a jumper) or sometimes you have to send a specific character within a period of time after reset, etc.

Comment: Arduinos are like this and some other products in the arduino world are like this the (board level) product is programmed to mate up with arduino drivers, but some can have their bootloaders erased/reprogrammed and then they no longer mate up until you use one of the native interfaces to program it (the stm32 blue pill is a perfect example of this, but there are very many others).

Comment: And yes the blue pill and a number of other products, you have to build your project in their sandbox so that the bootloader/programmer items are part of your project so that you can reprogram it again using that sandbox.  Not all but some blue pills you plug in see that it is supported by dfu-util, write some simple program that does not have the usb dfu-util support in it, you can easily write your new application, then it is game over you have to use a different interface after you have done this. (uart, swd, etc)

Comment: Many development boards contain two mcus one is the debugger the other the target, see st nucleo and discovery boards for example.  the target mcu is programmed using swd, from the debug mcu that you normally dont mess with, it speaks some usb protocol and then tools made for the host to talk to the debugger mcu...and the debugger mcu programs the target.  these days some debuggers mcu present themselves and removable thumb drives and you simply copy/drag and drop the binary file over no special tools.

Answer (score 1):

The microcontroller is in reality just a small and simple PC with an architecture (such as ARM) that you compile your program's source code against. In a normal PC after BIOS finishes its post test, it will search for an operating system, execute it and hand control over to that. The OS in turn has a process tree that hands over execution to a program's main() function. When main finishes executing it returns a code (usually 0) indicating successful completion and control returns to the OS.

In an embedded solution, there is no operating system. The BIOS loads your program's main() function instead of something like Linux or Windows, and it never returns a value because there is no host OS to return to.

Go take a look at AtmelStudio if you want to learn more about building and installing to the boards. C is still very common for embedded applications, really the only limitation as far as what language you use is whether your compiler can target the board's architecture.

Comment: *In an embedded solution, there is no operating system.* Embedded has a disturbingly broad definition these days. What you are describing is more "Bare Metal".

Comment: Yes that is certainly worth clarifying thank you